# OpenStreetMap Neighborhood Boundaries

Tags: openstreetmap, polygon, data, extents

Is it possible to download neighborhood boundaries from OpenStreetMap? I see on maps that they often indicate neighborhood names; is there a way to retrieve their coordinates and boundary polygon coordinates, much like the Zillow Neighborhood Boundaries data set?

Comment: What countries and regions are you looking for ?

Comment: Starting with major cities in UK, France, Germany. Chiefly London, Paris, Berlin, but ultimately looking for all major cities in Europe. Israel too.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? It is definitely possible that a company like Maponics might have what you're looking for. Can you provide any more details?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

New service from [MySociety](http://www.mysociety.org/) last week will get Administrative Boundaries for your chosen city.

Example **Paris**
[image]

http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/area/29746.html

**UK has better data source as using the OpenData from Ordnance Survey**

Example:
Birmingham, UK

note different url request

http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/2514.html

Comment: But it looks to me like what you refer to is only displaying the boundaries of the city (Paris), not of the neighbourhoods within the city. Or am I missing something? Sorry, I never worked with MySociety before

Comment: @NeStack different countries have different hierarchy for administrative boundaries. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative#10_admin_level_values_for_specific_countries

Answer (score 3):

Not from OpenStreetMap, but you can download Administrative Boundaries in many formats from the Global Administrative Areas database. They are heirarchial in nature (country>province> town>village, etc) and relatively acurate for popular places. http://www.gadm.org/

@Mapperz has identified the best answer to the question...However, I don't feel that OSM is a the best resource available for this type of task.

Comment: FYI -- their footer states: `These data are freely available for academic and other non-commercial use. Redistribution, or commercial use, is not allowed without prior permission.`

Comment: For the US they only provide the country outline, states, and counties, which is available on census.gov - https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html

Answer (score 2):

FYI, in my experience, OSM rarely has boundaries for neighborhoods, it usually just has a centroid point label.  Other sources would probably be better for boundaries. If you want to check, though, you can look up areas with [Nominatim](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/), and see what is in your areas of interest.  How Nominatim works and how to query is more fully described on its [OSM wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim)

Answer (score 0):

For the US and Canada you can download Neighborhood data (shapefile format) here:

- US: http://dinehere.us/neighborhoods.html
- CA: http://foodpages.ca/neighborhoods.html

Comment: That is great, but OP is looking for European cities according to comments.

Comment: Also, this is a HTML sitemap, not shapefiles that you can download and use

Comment: There are shapefiles on the top right corner: Click on " Download as shape file
" http://foodpages.ca/neighborhoods.tar.gz

Comment: FWIW the DineHere.us neighborhoods shapefile has no identifying information for the geographies, and the shapes have obviously been put through a very reductive simplification process. I'm not sure how anyone would effectively put them to use.