# Is there any site where I can found city shapes in postgreSQL polygon format

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, data

Is there any site where I can found city polygon area (for postgreSQL or similar)? I don't know if such resources exists, and I don't know how to find it.

Comment: The top answers on this question might also be useful for you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29067/openstreetmap-neighborhood-boundaries

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I did not know what words I should type for this search! (boundaries, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shapefiles (.shp) are a pretty standard format and can be read into postgreSQL ([see this question on how](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110854/importing-shp-to-postgresql)).  Doing a simple Google search for the city/cities/state you are looking for and shapefile should yield plenty of results.